# Not Able to FTP for Wget

Tags: server, ftp, wget

I am trying to do wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 on a VM at work... I'm ssh'd into the server via PuTTY.

When I try wget it keeps getting stuck on:

```
sudo wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
--2017-03-27 14:36:22--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
           => ‘gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2’
Resolving gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2 ... 1897483
==> PASV ... couldn't connect to 209.132.180.131 port 10190: Connection timed out
Retrying.
```

I have ufw enabled; however, I have tried to toggle on and off the ftp port to no avail.

Right now my ufw status is allowing 22 from my company's subnet . . . thought adding a rule that allowed 209.132.180.131 would help; however, it doesn't.

Any recommendations of what else to check?

Thanks!

Comment: 22 is the SSH port; nothing to do with FTP.

Comment: I get that, apologies for the confusion... I am just saying that, I was able to get SSH working with ufw; but, when I tried to put in FTP into ufw, it still wasn't working

Comment: Also, I disabled ufw and FTP still doesn't work

Comment: As it's a server "at work", it may be behind a company firewall which does not allow ports like 10190. Why not use http:?

Comment: Fair enough. Do you mean just download it? I can SFTP it via filezilla; but, I was hoping there'd be an easier way

Comment: You may use http mirrors like e.g. [netgull](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2) with wget.

Comment: Ah, OK... that's what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I Have to put this as an answer because i can't make a comment due to low rep)

Try using `wget --no-passive-ftp`. There might be a problem trying to access the passive port.

Comment: Thanks! That gives a different output, but still won't go through:

`--2017-03-27 15:20:01--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
           => ‘gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2’
Resolving gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2 ... 1897483
==> PORT ... done.    ==> RETR gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2 ... `

Comment: Is there anymore to that? It shows it was able to connect to using the PORT command  (port 20) and it issued the RETR command. After that, it should be downloading.

Comment: It still got stuck... I was able to get it via the http mirror at netgull as pointed out above. Thanks for your help though!!